# Hardware Requirements for Camera and sensor

Tags: ros, hardware, cpu, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to figure out how much computing power do I need for my robot.
I plan to put 2 cameras that will use OpenCV for detection of colors, shapes, etc.. and a laser distance sensor (not a lidar sensor, but a simple single-dimension laser sensor).

Some of the sensors and of the cameras will not be fixed, but will be mounted on moving parts, ROS will have to consider their physical location and insert it in a 3D environment with the model of the robot.

I have no idea of the computing power required for these processes, i'm currently thought to this configuration:

AMD A4-3400 dual-core 2.7GHz

2x 2GB RAM (total 4GB)

Is it enough or do I need at least a tri-core processor with 8GB of RAM?

PS: sorry for my bad english, i'm italian.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76378/hardware-requirements-for-camera-and-sensor/) by [Extar](https://answers.ros.org/users/6373/extar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it depends on the cameras and your speed limit. but if the images are 640x480 and you don't do anything crazy you can achieve real-time with that setup.

---

Originally posted by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) with karma: 200 on 2013-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Extar](https://answers.ros.org/users/6373/extar/) on 2013-09-05**:
Thanks for the reply. The cameras will be 640x480 or less, and I hope I don't do anything crazy, so I suppose that setup is enough.